# Switching between codes in my program

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I have three programs calculating PI and I want to refactor it into one. I can't get it working using an `if` or `switch` command. It is something to do with case 3.

```
public class ProgramPI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int z = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wybierz metode liczenia PI 1=Leibnitz 2=Wallis 3=MonteCarlo:"));{

            switch(z){
            case 1:

            double pi=0;
            double mianownik=1;

            double i = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Obliczamy PI metoda Leibnitza podaj n: "));
            for (int x = 0; x < i; x++){
                // obliczanie ciagu
                if (x % 2 == 0) {
                    pi = pi + (1 / mianownik);
                } else {
                    pi=pi - (1 / mianownik);
                }
                mianownik = mianownik + 2;
            }
            pi = pi * 4;
            System.out.println("Przy n= " + i + " Pi = " + pi);
    break;      
    case 2:
                double termCount = 2;
                double polpi = 1;
                double termin;
                // double termino2 =0;
                double n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Liczymy Pi wzorem Wallisa, podaj n:"));
                for (double j = 0; j <= n; j++)
                {
                termin = (termCount / (termCount-1));
                // System.out.println(termin);
                polpi = polpi * termin;
                termin = (termCount / (termCount+1));
                // System.out.println(termin+" "+ mediopi);
                polpi = polpi * termin;

                termCount= termCount + 2;
                }
                System.out.println("Ilosc wyrazen = " + termCount);
                polpi = polpi * 2;
                System.out.println("Przy n= " + n + " Pi wynosi: " + polpi);
            break;
    case 3:

                    static double podajPi(int liczbaStrzalow) {
                        int wKole = 0;
                        // generowanie punktów
                        for (int i = 0; i < liczbaStrzalow; i++) {
                            double x = Math.random();
                            double y = Math.random();
                            // Sprawdzanie, czy punkt jest w kole 
                            // r = 1, więc r * r = 1
                            if ((x * x + y * y) <= 1) {
                                wKole++;
                            }
                        }
                        // obliczanie stosunku liczby punktów w kole do wszystkich punktów
                        double s = (double) wKole / liczbaStrzalow;
                        return 4 * s;
                    }


                        System.out.println("Pi = " + Math.PI);
                        // obliczanie Pi dla 00, 1000, 10 000, 100 000 oraz 1000 000 punktów
                        // można to zrobić za pomocą pętli
                        for (int i = 100; i <= 1000000; i *= 10) {
                            double pi = podajPi(i);
                            System.out.println("Dla " + i + " punktów Pi = " + pi + "\n"
                                    + "błąd =  " + (pi - Math.PI));
                        }

                    }



            { 



            }
                }
```

Comment: You can't embed a method in a `switch` or an `if`.

Comment: So what's the solution here I tried everything from my basic knowledge and what I found in google. As I mentioned I am bad programmer.

Comment: Please start with cleanly formatting your code. Then refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Note that your skill as a programmer is immaterial: if you want help, you need to help us help you. Be clear. Be concise.

Comment: Create the method `podajPi` first. Then call it in your `case` block.

Comment: I suggest you start with code which compiles and runs and only then add to it.  If you start with a mess and add a mess you will end up with a mess.

Comment: I would also try to make the maths simpler and you will have less to code and it will be faster.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the support. Code above works until case 3. But nevermind that. I found simplified method in the net and added it to my code and it works now :D
I should really learn a bit more about coding :)